# React native WebView prevent openUrl

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I'm using webview from react-native to show a simple browser, however right now I have the problem whenever I open a website like Amazon and I have the app installed on my phone it pushes me to the app like Linking.openUrl would. How can I prevent this behaviour, I would like to stay in my WebView on every site. This is my code:

```
   <WebView
      source={{ uri: link }}
      style={styles.webView}
      geolocationEnabled={true}
      allowsLinkPreview={false}
      automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
      onNavigationStateChange={e => this.setState({ link: e.url })}
      onLoadStart={() => this.setState({ loading: true })}
      onLoadEnd={() => this.setState({ loading: false })}
      ref={ref => (this.webView = ref)}
    />
```

It seems like there is no prop to solve this, does anyone has an idea how I can achieve that?

Comment: even when you fisrt open the app this will happen ????

Comment: try to use google.com for example see what happen

Comment: Im simulating the app on my physical iPhone, on this phone I have amazon installed, whenever I open amazon.com in the WebView it leaves the app im working on and opens the amazon app, however I would like to prevent this behaviour and stay in the simulated app

Comment: Google works fine